# How can I install my bundled JRE somewhere other than ${installer:sys.installationDir}/jre?

Tags: install4j

Ok this was a little hard for me to put into words, so bear with me.

Our project directory structure relies on ${sys.installationDir}/jre being the location of the JRE being used to run our product.  This works fine for new installs using install4j built installers, since install4j defaults to placing the jre there.

But for install4j built updates to legacy installations this is problematic.

I have installation code I'm reusing that unfortunately relies on Java 1.6 functionality.  I have legacy installs of our product that are running 1.5 and can't be updated for other reasons.

I need to allow an install4j installer to unpack a Java 1.6 jre into a temporary location, used only for executing the installation code, and then remove it.

I can't seem to find a way to configure the location of the install of the bundled JRE.  Any tips/advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JRE bundles are always installed to the "jre" subdirectory inside the installation directory.

You can deselect the "Update bundled JRE" property on the "Install files" action to prevent the old JRE from being overwritten.

Comment: Hmmm OK, that only helps if the installer will still use the new bundled JRE to run the installation code. I'll test that.  If that's not the case I guess my only option is to manually install the bundled JRE in some other location, as some sort of pre-install action?  Also, can I add "Make JRE location configurable" to a list of install4j feature requests?

Comment: @Frank Yes, the bundled JRE will always be used for the installer. The configurable JRE folder is already in the issue tracker :-)